# Cppcheck: (error) Resource leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I am doing some learning with C, and am having trouble identifying a memory leak situation

When I check code with cppcheck: get (error) Resource leak: f

```
enum bus_type {
    MEDIA_BUS_UNKNOWN,
    MEDIA_BUS_VIRTUAL,
    MEDIA_BUS_PCI,
    MEDIA_BUS_USB,
};

static enum bus_type get_bus(char *device)
{
        char file[PATH_MAX];
        char s[1024];
        FILE *f;

        if (!strcmp(device, "/sys/devices/virtual"))
                return MEDIA_BUS_VIRTUAL;

        snprintf(file, PATH_MAX, "%s/modalias", device);
        f = fopen(file, "r");
        if (!f)
                return MEDIA_BUS_UNKNOWN;
        if (!fgets(s, sizeof(s), f))       /* <-- (error) Resource leak: f */
                return MEDIA_BUS_UNKNOWN;
        fclose(f);

        if (!strncmp(s, "pci", 3))
                return MEDIA_BUS_PCI;
        if (!strncmp(s, "usb", 3))
                return MEDIA_BUS_USB;

        return MEDIA_BUS_UNKNOWN;
}
```

I feel I am missing something with the memory management.

Comment: You should probably close `f` before returning `MEDIA_BUS_UNKNOWN` in the second case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `fclose` the file that you have `fopen`ed earlier in the function, or otherwise you leak the resources allocated and pointed at by the `FILE*`.

For example:

```
if (!fgets(s, sizeof(s), f)) {
     fclose(f);
     return MEDIA_BUS_UNKNOWN;
}
```

Hope this helps!