# Resource leak or false positive

Tags: c++, static-analysis, filehandle, cppcheck, file-pointer

I have a code like this:

```
std::string getInfo(FILE *fp)
{
    char buffer[30];
    if (fread(buffer, 19, 1, fp) == 1)
        buffer[19] = '\0';
    else
        buffer[0] = '\0';

    return buffer;
}
```

I'm using cppcheck for static analysis and it spits a warning:

```
error: Resource leak: fp [resourceLeak]
 return buffer;
 ^
```

The way I see it, since the return is by value, the data will be copied from "buffer" into std::string's storage, so there's no leak there.

Does this pose some real problem or is it a false positive?

Comment: It looks like it's complaining about your file pointer and not the buffer or std::string.

Comment: @Voo: which still is presumably the caller's responsibility to `fclose`

Comment: However, this code does look buggy.  It's not a good idea to have the `std::string` constructor just figure out the length using `strlen` when you already know the amount of data read from the file.  Or is it your intention to trim at the first NUL byte (but still read a full 19 bytes from the file advancing the internal read pointer)?  A documentation comment would go a long way.

Comment: @BenVoigt Which may or may not be happening in his program. We can't see that. I would assume cppcheck can and is.

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17077907/10871073 If that's the only place in the code where `fp` is used and it is *not* closed in the calling module, then maybe cppcheck reports the leak there?

Comment: @Ben Sure, my point was that it's the parameter the OP should focus on, since the std::string/buffer code will not cause any leak. It's possible that the passed in file pointer isn't released from the caller for some reason..

Comment: Milan, please expand this into a proper example: A program which cppcheck complains about, not just a function.

Comment: Good catch. I was reading through so much output, I completely missed the "fp" part. Yeah, there's fopen with missing fclose. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> error: Resource leak: fp [resourceLeak]

You are not leaking any resource *from this function*. So, if you're only analyzing this function, this is a bug in your cppcheck. However, as @Taekahn points out - maybe the leak is elsewhere in your program.

Also, since you're returning `std::string`, you can use a [constructor taking a pointer and a count](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), and not bother with the '\0' in the buffer:

```
std::string getInfo(FILE *fp)
{
    static constexpr const std::size_t info_length { 19 };
    char buffer[info_length];
    if (fread(buffer, info_length, 1, fp) == 1)
        return {buffer, info_length};
    else
        return {};
}
```

If you're using C++23, you might consider returning an [`std::expected`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70571282/1593077) instead of the empty string, e.g. something like:

```
std::expected<std::string, errc> getInfo(FILE *fp)
{
    static constexpr const std::size_t info_length { 19 };
    char buffer[info_length];
    if (fread(buffer, info_length, 1, fp) == 1)
        return std::string{buffer, info_length};
    else
        return std::unexpected{errno};
}
```

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: Maybe he is leaking the resource. We can't see the rest of the program. cppcheck can.

Comment: Not an answer, just a guess. Maybe OP calls `getInfo(fopen(path));` and does not show it in a [mcve].

Comment: @273K: That's possible. I'd make this comment on the question to get OP's attention though.

Comment: Just to confirm, the issue was a missing fclose(). I was so focused on string memory that I missed the "fp" in the cppcheck output. Thanks!

Comment: @MilanBabuškov It's unbelievable, you, who has reached 57.3k scores, did not post a [mcve] like a newbie on SO and caused other users blaming cppcheck.

Comment: @273K: It's not unbelievable, because Milan's post insinuated that cppcheck was complaining about _this function per se_, so that it was an MRE.

Answer (score 3):

There is no leak in the shown function.

The `std::FILE*` provided as the argument may have been created using `std::fopen`, and such resource may leak if it isn't closed at some point. But since this function doesn't acquire the resource, this function shouldn't be responsible for releasing it either.

In conclusion, it's either a false positive or misleading diagnostic. At best (from point of view of the diagnostic), there may be a leak somewhere else, although that's not demonstrated within the example.

---

P.S. Since you return a `std::string`, you can avoid copying the content first into a separate buffer by reading directly into the `std::string`:

```
constexpr std::size_t count = 19;
std::string buffer(count, '\0');
std::size_t r = fread(buffer.data(), count, 1, fp);
if (r)
    return buffer;
else
    return {};
```

Comment: @eerorika: I also missed that at first...

Comment: Ah, that's a very cool idea. I never though to allocate the memory to string directly. I'll try to start using that in my code. Thanks.

Comment: 1. You're repeating 19 twice. 2.  You can use `auto` for r.

Comment: @einpoklum 1. Fixed. 2. You can use `auto`, but you don't have to. You can use `auto` for `count` too (it won't matter that it would be `int`).